# SQL to search with a subsets of records

Tags: sql, db2, subset

Is there any way to select all subsets from table A where corresponding subsets exist in table B? Each subset in table A must have at least all the entries that corresponding subset in table B.

In [this link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) it's called "Division with a Remainder" but my problem is more complex because I've got many to many relation.

**Table A**

UserName text | File text | AccessLevel int

**Table B**

AppName text | File text | AccessLevel int

**Sample data**

Table A

```
User1 | aaa.txt | 1
User1 | bbb.txt | 3
User1 | ccc.txt | 1
User2 | aaa.txt | 3
```

Table B

```
Appl1 | aaa.txt | 1
Appl1 | bbb.txt | 1
Appl2 | aaa.txt | 1
Appl3 | bbb.txt | 5
Appl4 | aaa.txt | 1
Appl4 | bbb.txt | 1
Appl4 | ccc.txt | 1
Appl4 | ddd.txt | 1
```

Expected results:

```
User1 | Appl1
User1 | Appl2
User2 | Appl2
```

User1 has "complete" access to applications Appl1 and Appl2 because he has necessary access to ALL files used by these applications. He doesn't have access to application Appl3 because access level is not high enough. He doesn't have access to application Appl4 because he doesn't have access to file ddd.txt.

Basically I need to compare subsets of records and return all cases where subset in table B is equal or greater than subset in table A. Is there any way to do it in SQL?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought of using stored procedure? I don't have access to DB2 but my recommendation would be to use a stored procedure with cursors for user and for app.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have, I could even write some REXX script to do it. However, I had a feeling that it can be done with SQL but I jus don't have necessary skills to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a self-join and then comparing the number of matching records to the number needed for the application.

Assuming no duplicates:

```
select a.username, b.appname
from a join
     (select b.*, count(*) over (partition by b.appname) as cnt
      from b
     ) b
     on a.filetext = b.filetext and
        a.accesslevel >= b.accesslevel
group by a.username, b.appname, b.cnt
having count(*) = b.cnt
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked DB2 documentation and looks that it doesn't support  OVER PARTITION BY. However, I got the idea behind this select so will try to mimic it without using OVER PARTITION BY.

Comment: @KrisKelvin . . . DB2 *definitely* supports window functions and has for many years.  IBM calls this functionality OLAP functionality and it is documented here:  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_olapspecification.html.

Comment: Apologies, you're right, I must have missed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct A1.USERNAME, B1.APPLICATION
FROM TABLEUSER A1
INNER JOIN TABLEAPPLI B1 on B1.filename=A1.filename and B1.accesslevel<=A1.accesslevel
where not exists
(
select * 
from TABLEUSER A2 INNER JOIN TABLEAPPLI B2 on B2.filename<>A2.filename or B2.accesslevel>A2.accesslevel 
where (A1.USERNAME, B1.APPLICATIONAME) = (A2.USERNAME, B2.APPLICATIONAME)
)
```